# Como randomizar um Array em c++

Tags: array, c++, random, números-aleatórios

Existe muito material aqui sobre metodos de ordenação de arrays (quicksort, bubblesort e etc.) , mas eu queria saber se existe um método de "desordenação" de arrays, ou seja, embaralhar os elementos de um array.

*Até existem perguntas aqui sobre esse tema, mas elas são sobre java ou C#.

**Por favor, alem de mostrar o algoritmo, teria como explicar a logica por trás ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O algoritmo [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) de `<algorithm>` faz exatamente o que você descreve:

```
template<typename RandomIt, typename Gen>
void shuffle(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Gen&& g)
{
    using diff_t = typename std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::difference_type;
    using distr_t = std::uniform_int_distribution<diff_t>;
    using param_t = typename distr_t::param_type;

    distr_t D;
    diff_t n = last - first;
    for (diff_t i = n-1; i > 0; --i)
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(first[i], first[D(g, param_t(0, i))]);
    }
}
```

A ideia é iterar o intervalo [first, last) de trás pra frente (`i` começando em `n-1` até `1`), trocando cada elemento em sequência com algum outro aleatório, que esteja no intervalo [0, i].

Exemplo de uso do `std::shuffle`:

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    // Motor com semente gerada por `rd`.
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());

    // Embaralha o vetor `v` usando o motor de números aleatórios `g`.
    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);

    // A partir daqui, `v` está com seus elementos embaralhados.
}
```

Comment: Fiquei pensando um pouco sobre esse algoritmo da implementação padrão. Ele é muito esperto.

Answer (score 1):

Desordenar um conjunto de elementos não é uma operação tão comum quanto ordenar, por tal não é assunto tão recorrente.

Aqui está um exemplo de um algoritmo para embaralhar um vetor:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> geraDesordenado(std::vector<T> V)
{
    static std::mt19937 G(42); //gerador de números aleatórios
    std::vector<T> R; //buffer de resultado
    while(!V.empty())
    {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> 
             d(0, V.size()-1); //probabilidade linear entre índices restantes (de zero até tamanho-1)
        auto i = V.begin()+d(G); //gera iterador para posição sorteada
        R.push_back(*i); //copia elemento sorteado
        V.erase(i);      //apaga elemento sorteado
    }
    return R;
}
```

Ele funciona sorteando os índices aleatórios de um vetor, extraindo um elemento por vez, até esvaziá-lo.

[Este exemplo online](http://cpp.sh/6ur5z) mostra a saída quando a aplica a um vetor de `string`s:

```
Vetor original:
  Quanta ordem entre dois coelhos? 
Exemplos desordenados:
  ordem coelhos? dois Quanta entre 
  dois entre ordem Quanta coelhos? 
  Quanta ordem entre dois coelhos?
```

Bem, esse código eu fiz só pra lhe fornecer um exemplo de algoritmo, como você pediu. Na prática, existem método mais eficientes e recomendados, incluindo uma função na biblioteca `std`, a [`std::shuffle`](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)

Comment: Cuidado: `std::random_shuffle` foi descontinuado, dando lugar ao novo `std::shuffle`.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi Editado, vlw